# Android WebView Xamarin ERR_CACHE_WRITE_FAILURE

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

I'm having this intermittent error happening when I load my site in an Android  HybridWebView in Xamarin Forms app where the site becomes blank (no content is displayed).

I added an OnReceivedError method to my WebViewClient implementation and found that I'm getting the following error:

Description: ERR_CACHE_WRITE_FAILURE
ErrorCode: Unknown

The Url where this is happening is the bundle.js for my site.

I can semi-workaround this issue by reloading the site by doing the following:

```
        Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
        Control.ClearHistory();
        Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
        Control.LoadUrl(Element.Uri);            
        InjectJS(JavaScriptFunction);
```

The site is displayed correctly but my JavaScriptFunction is not Injected into my site. I use this javascript function to communicate back to my xamarin app.

Has anyone seen this before?
I would love to understand how to handle/avoid that ERR_CACHE_WRITE_FAILURE error so I don't have to do any workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: Not able to reproduce this issue, maybe you can share your demo?

Comment: Hi York Shen, I would have to give you the code for my whole app and that is not feasible. The error does not happen all the time but it seems like it happens when trying to get the bundle.js file in my webapp. I see you are part of MSFT, do you have more insights about ERR_CACHE_WRITE_FAILURE in general?? I was not able to find much about it. Thanks!!